# A question from definition of coercive function.

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, coercive

I have one doubt about the definition of Coercive function:

Definition:
if for a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$:
$$
\lim_{\|x\| \to +\infty} f(x) = +\infty,
$$
then $f$ is a coercive function.

As I checked in the literature, it is defined on $\mathbb R^n$; is it true it only defines on $\mathbb R^n$ or we can define also on its subsets?
Now, could we define a coercive function on a domain like $x \in [0, +\infty)\subset \mathbb{R}$? For example, please clearly determine below each one is coercive or not:

1. $f(x) = x^2$ for $\text{dom}(f) = \mathbb{R}$; coercive or not coercive?
2. $f(x) = x^2$ for $\text{dom}(f) = [0,+\infty)$; coercive or not coercive?
3. $f(x) = x^2$ for $\text{dom}(f) = [0,1]$; coercive or not coercive?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition is meaningful in any topological space. In normed spaces, it requires the possibility for the domain to include elements of arbitrarily large norm. Hence the definition can be formally given in any subset that... "contains infinity". It can be written as
$$
\lim_{\substack{\|x\| \to +\infty \\ x \in X}} f(x) = +\infty,
$$
where $X$ is the domain of $f$.

Comment: Dear @Siminore: based on your explanation, my conclusion is: "For a function, which its domain is any subset of such a normed space contains infinity, that takes infinite value in infinity is coercive."; is it correct?

Comment: In calculus of variations it seems that little attention is paid to the domain of the function(al), since it is naturally a whole (sub)space. From the topological viewpoint, much less is necessary to define coercivity.

Comment: In the literature we have: if $\lim_{\|x\| \to +\infty} f(x) = +\infty$, then $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is coercive function. So, is that mean the word "if" refers to the first part or last part of the definition: "if $x$ goes to infinity, then the functional value is infinity"; so, if it does not approach to infinity, is it still coercive (like: $x \in [0,1]$ for above example)? Or, is it necessary for the function domain to approach infinity any way even one sided as above?

Comment: That definition applies only to globally defined functions.

Comment: so, dear @Siminore, based on your explanation above it means: also, we can define a coercive function on an one sided unbound domain (the example above). Now, is it necessary condition for a coercive function to be in whole space or even a subset but unbounded? I mean, we cannot say a function with domain $x \in [0,1]$ is coercive, can we?

Comment: Well, coercivity in some sense replaces compactness of the domain. If the domain is itself a compact set, coercivity becomes unnecessary. But some... unboundedness of the domain might suffice to weaken the basic definition of coercivity.

Comment: Please check the question again.

Comment: Your question is meaningless unless you **define** coercivity for general domains.

Comment: This is just an example; you @Siminore gave a definition and some explanations, then I would like to know the answer based on your own points! Based on your answer, 1 and 2 are coercive but 3 is not coercive; aren't them?

Comment: Yes, in any reasonable sense.